# Tag request: Samsung Galaxy Note 5

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

See [Every so often, the volume on my Samsung Galaxy Note 5 will oscillate wildly. How do I make that stop?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/210590/every-so-often-the-volume-on-my-samsung-galaxy-note-5-will-oscillate-wildly-ho) - I can't make it myself, sadly, so I must ask you.

Comment: Also, you're missing everything up to the Note 9.

Comment: ...wait, [galaxy-note-5] is a tag?  why did I not *think* of that.

Comment: Nevertheless, could you alias [samsung-galaxy-note-5] and etc. in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the heads-up, [galaxy-note-5](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/galaxy-note-5) has been renamed and synonymized to [samsung-galaxy-note-5](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/samsung-galaxy-note-5).

```
Master tag 'samsung-galaxy-note-5' doesn't exist, renaming to 'galaxy-note-5'
rename result: 1 rows affected
tag remapping of [samsung-galaxy-note-5] and [galaxy-note-5] complete!
Tag Synonym galaxy-note-5 -> samsung-galaxy-note-5 was approved!
```

---

Currently, these are the available tags for Samsung Galaxy Note series:

- [samsung-galaxy-note](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/samsung-galaxy-note)
- [samsung-galaxy-note-2](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/samsung-galaxy-note-2)
- [samsung-galaxy-note-3](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/samsung-galaxy-note-3)
- [samsung-galaxy-note-4](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/samsung-galaxy-note-4)
- [samsung-galaxy-note-5](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/samsung-galaxy-note-5)
- [samsung-galaxy-note-7](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/samsung-galaxy-note-7)
- [samsung-galaxy-note-8](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/samsung-galaxy-note-8)
- [samsung-galaxy-note-9](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/samsung-galaxy-note-9)
- [samsung-galaxy-note-10.1](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/samsung-galaxy-note-10.1)

Are there anything that is still missing and their related questions? Note that tags cannot be created if there are no questions to be tagged.

Comment: I can't think of anything.  Thanks!